# statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function Qt/C++

Tags: qt, memory-address

```
void RollsRoyceTab::stateRRChanged(int)
 {
     stateRR = checkBoxRollsRoyce->checkState();
     if(stateRR) emit signal_rr_alg; else emit signal_rr_manual;
 }
```

error in stateRR  statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emit` is just syntactic sugar - it doesn't actually do anything and is preprocessed out of the C++ code. What follows `emit` must be a valid function call, not a signal name.

Change your code to this (assuming no parameters to the signals):

```
if(stateRR)
  emit signal_rr_alg();
else
  emit signal_rr_manual();
```

(Note that a single signal with a boolean or enum parameter could be a bit better - depends on what you connect those signals to though.)